# Recursive calls using hooks

Tags: reactjs

Im having a problema with recursive hook calls when I try to remove the `Line 83:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setLoadingStatus'. Either include it or remove the dependency array` message.

I have a hook that sets the "loading" status of my application:

```js
export const useLoadingStatus = () => {
  const [
    {
      progressBar: { isLoading, ...pbp },
    },
    dispatcher,
  ] = useContext()
  const setLoading = ({ isLoading, ...options }: AppProgressBarStatus) => {
    dispatcher(isLoading ? Loading(options) : NotLoading())
  }
  return [{ isLoading, ...pbp }, setLoading] as [
    AppProgressBarStatus,
    (options: AppProgressBarStatus) => void,
  ]
}
```

So in my app,I want this attribute `isLoading: true` until my dependencies are not ready ( this dependencies depends on external requests ).

Im doing this:

```js
const [dependencies, setDependencies] = useState<Dependencies>([])
const [, setLoadingStatus] = useLoadingStatus()

useEffect(() => {
  externalRequest(pagination).then(response => setDependencies(response.data))
}, [pagination])

useEffect(() => {
  setLoadingStatus({isLoading: !dependencies.length})
}, [dependencies])
```

This works fine but with the quoted warning ( CI wont allow me to deploy this app with warnings and I dont want to use `// eslint-disable-next-line` unless it's really necessary and I understand 100% of the reason ).

But if I include `setLoadingStatus` on dependencies array of 2nd `useEffect` Ill have hook calls every render ( causing a loop of calls ).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

ESLint is a tool that helps you avoid errors. In this particular case you can either disable said rule, because you know that `setLoadingStatus` shouldn't affect dependencies, or you can add it to dependencies, but you have to ensure that your reference to this function doesn't change between renders. It is achievable with [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook:

```js
export const useLoadingStatus = () => {
  const [
    {
      progressBar: { isLoading, ...pbp },
    },
    dispatcher,
  ] = useContext();
  const setLoading = useCallback(
    ({ isLoading, ...options }: AppProgressBarStatus) => {
      dispatcher(isLoading ? Loading(options) : NotLoading());
    },
    []
  );
  return [{ isLoading, ...pbp }, setLoading] as [
    AppProgressBarStatus,
    (options: AppProgressBarStatus) => void
  ];
};
```

Comment: It didn't work as expected (although it removed the warnings and stopped recursive rendering). Now I try to change the attr `isLoading` value from false to true and it always remains false.

Comment: Could this have happened because the setter returns void and as the value is memoized so the dispatcher is never called?

Comment: I'm not sure. It is possible that "useCallback" doesn't work with arguments,as I never tried to use it like this before.

Comment: Can you make a sandbox with similar case, so it would be possible to actually run the code?